# Sets idenified by SonarQube as not serializable

Tags: sonarqube, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I have an Entity with a Set of AuditRecords:

```
private Set<AuditRecord> auditRecords;
```

AuditRecord implements Serializable.

However the Sonar scan identifies this Set and other Sets in other Entities as Critical issues:

```
Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable : Make "auditRecords" transient or serializable.
```

JPA2 supports Sets. Why is this marked as a critical issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.util.Set` does not implement `java.io.Serializable`: there is no guarantee that the implementation of Set which will be used at run time is serializable. Hence the issue raised by SonarQube.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug[SONARJAVA-1061](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1061), You need to upgrade the sonar-java plugin 3.3 or more.

[Downloads sonar-java plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/releases)

[see Installing a Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+a+Plugin)